# Java Wildcard ошибка

Tags: java

Как правильно написать метод?

```
    private HashMap<?, ?> zip(List<?> k, List<?> v) {
        if (ensure(k, v))
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        HashMap<?, ?> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
            map.put(k.get(i), v.get(i));

        return map;
    }
```

В строке, где put, пишет [image]

Comment: Если вы вместо нормальных обобщений используете чистые символы `?`, то тогда уж можно и вовсе обойтись сырыми типами. Например, можете заменить тип мапы на просто `HashMap`, тогда ваш код заработает.

Comment: действительно, теперь работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеет смысл избавиться от wildcard и сделать метод обобщённым и/или утилитарным (статическим), чтобы обеспечить контроль типов.

Также в методе `zip` не определена переменная `keys`, которая скорей всего должна быть заменена на список ключей `k`, и лучше, чтобы он возвращал интерфейс `Map`, а не конкретную реализацию `HashMap`:

```java
private <K, V> Map<K, V> zip(List<K> keys, List<V> values) {
    if (ensure(keys, values)) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0, n = keys.size(); i < n; i++) {
        map.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
    }
    return map;
}
```

---

Вариант с использованием Stream API:

```java
private static <K, V> Map<K, V> zipp(List<K> keys, List<V> values) {
    if (keys.size() != values.size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    return IntStream.range(0, keys.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(keys.get(i), values.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v2));
}
```

---

***Обновление***

Если требуется объединить несколько списков (чтобы одному ключу отвечало несколько значений), могут быть следующие варианты:

- создать мапу со значениями-списками `Map<K, List<?>>` -- "грязный" способ

```java
private static <K, V, E> Map<K, List<?>> zipp(List<K> keys, List<V> first, List<E> second) {
    if (keys.size() != first.size() || keys.size() != second.size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    return IntStream.range(0, keys.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(keys.get(i), List.of(first.get(i), second.get(i))))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v2));
}
```

- более чистый вариант - использовать типизированный класс-контейнер типа пары `Pair<V, E>` (например, при помощи типизированного кортежа record):

```java
record Pair<V, E>(V first, E second){}

private static <K, V, E> Map<K, Pair<V, E>> zippp(List<K> keys, List<V> first, List<E> second) {
    if (keys.size() != first.size() || keys.size() != second.size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    return IntStream.range(0, keys.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(keys.get(i), new Pair<>(first.get(i), second.get(i))))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v2));
}
```

Тесты:

```java
List<Integer> k = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2);
List<String> v = Arrays.asList("aa", "bb", "cc", "xx", "yy", "pp");
List<Double> e = Arrays.asList(2.0, 4d, 8d, 10d, 4d, 5d);

System.out.println(zipp(k, v));      // Map<Integer, String>
System.out.println(zipp(k, v, e));   // Map<Integer, List<?>>
System.out.println(zippp(k, v, e));  // Map<Integer, Pair<String, Double>>
```

Результат:

```
{1=aa, 2=pp, 3=cc, 4=xx, 5=yy}
{1=[aa, 2.0], 2=[pp, 5.0], 3=[cc, 8.0], 4=[xx, 10.0], 5=[yy, 4.0]}
{1=Pair[first=aa, second=2.0], 2=Pair[first=pp, second=5.0], 3=Pair[first=cc, second=8.0], 4=Pair[first=xx, second=10.0], 5=Pair[first=yy, second=4.0]}
```

Comment: проблема в том, что я создаю мапу из ключа и двух значений, написать два метода zip(List<K> k, List<V> v) и zip(List<K> k, List<E> v) не получится, они пересекаются ( пишет clashes )

Comment: в общем, мне нужно, чтобы тип принимал любой дженерик из K, V, E, это возможно?

Comment: Что значит _"из ключа и двух значений"_?  У значений могут быть разные типы?  Или у ключей тоже?

Comment: да, то есть, ключ : первое значение, второе значение, я пробую сделать это так: 
'''
    private ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<K> keys;
    private ArrayList<V> firstValues;
    private ArrayList<E> secondValues;

Comment: у каждого свой тип

Comment: Может быть вариант с тем, что будет строиться мапа со значением-контейнером, т.е. в качестве значения будет либо пара `Pair<V, E>` -> `Map<K, Pair<V, E>>`, либо контейнер с wildcard `List<?>` -> `Map<K, List<?>>`

Comment: @trigeminalneuralgia, см. обновление ответа

Comment: отличное решение, спасибо